# Where is the right place to install the ESX vSphere?

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I have one server with 6 hotplug 300G SAS HDD.

Where is the right place to install the ESX vSphere?

6 HDD RAID10 for datastore and ESX vSphere together

-------- OR --------

2 HDD RAID1 for ESX vSphere

4 HDD RAID10 for datastore

Thanks to all helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VSphere ESXi installation is tiny (<8GB), you'll be wasting a huge amount of space putting it on it's own RAID 1. Go with option 1.

Answer (score 1):

Install it on a separate USB stick as VMware intends it, preferably stuck in a port inside the server (most servers have internal USB ports), and leave the HDDs for datastore space.